# Is it possible to retrieve file path/url information when querying BULK OPENROWSET in Azure Synapse?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am able to retrieve all the keys and values from json files stored in a Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 directory through an Azure Synapse Serverless SQL query like the one below:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    someColumn1,
    someColumn2
FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'https://********.dfs.core.windows.net/some/path/**',
   FORMAT = 'csv',
   FIELDTERMINATOR ='0x0b',
   FIELDQUOTE = '0x0b',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0b' 
) WITH (doc NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ROWS
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON ( [doc] )
WITH (
    [someColumn1] INT '$.someProperty1',
    [someColumn2] INT '$.someProperty2'
) AS someData
```

I am looking to retrieve the path/url of the JSON files for parsing as extra columns returned by my SQL query. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Synapse provides the `filepath` function that returns a full or partial path:

> - The whole file path from which the row was retrieved is returned when the function is invoked without an argument. DATA SOURCE returns path relative to DATA SOURCE when used in OPENROWSET.
> - A portion of the route that matches the wildcard on the point indicated in the argument is returned when the function is invoked with a parameter. The path's first wildcard-matching portion, for instance, would be returned if parameter value 1 were used.

**Yes, you can get file path in synapse** with the additional columns along with query file.

**Example:**

```sql
SELECT  TOP  100
name,salary,ROWS.filepath() AS  filepath
FROM
OPENROWSET(
BULK  'https://dlsg2p.dfs.core.windows.net/fsn2p/userdetails.json',
FORMAT = 'CSV',
FIELDQUOTE = '0x0b',
FIELDTERMINATOR ='0x0b',
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0b'=
)
WITH (doc NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS  ROWS
OUTER  APPLY OPENJSON ( [doc] )
WITH (
[name] VARCHAR  '$.name',
[salary] INT  '$.salary'
) AS someData
```

**Execution and Output:**

[image]

Reference: [file Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-specific-files)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I searched the Microsoft documentation for hours trying to find this. I knew it must have been possible. Thanks again.